# How to get more than two visual rows with GtkColumnView in GTK4?

Tags: go, gtk4

From the few examples out there it looked like you set the visible area with a ScrollBox around a ColumnView. I've done this giving the ScrollBox about 10 rows of height. However, whenever I run it it just creates two rows. If I move my cursor over I can see it's creating new rows by the label which has a count in it. However, visually there is never more than two rows. I've played with VExpand on various objects from various examples but I not getting any change.

I load the ColumnView From a UI file and then create two columns in code and then have a little code to add items to the lists in the model as it requests. My understanding is that it's supposed to just keep adding rows until it fills up the visual space which in my mind should be about 10 rows.

Here's the code and UI file (cut down to show mostly just what's necessary). Also an image to show what it ends up like. Note in the image the numbers 49 & 50. It's starts at 1 & 2 but if mouse up and down over the two rows it starts adding showing it is creating new rows. At the moment I have no code to remove rows so I'm not sure how it's possible to stay at just two visible when there is space for the ColumnView to expand into.

In the code you can probably ignore everything above the `setup()` function, it's just there for completeness but all the relevant stuff starts in `setup()`.

```golang
package scratches

import (
    `strconv`
    `time`

    `github.com/diamondburned/gotk4/pkg/gtk/v4`

    `gitlab.com/trading5124936/tradinganalyzer.git/analyzer/dbLayer`
    `gitlab.com/trading5124936/tradinganalyzer.git/analyzer/gui/fields/checkButton`
    `gitlab.com/trading5124936/tradinganalyzer.git/analyzer/gui/fields/timezone`
    `gitlab.com/trading5124936/tradinganalyzer.git/analyzer/gui/interfaces`
)

type fields struct {
    apply    *checkButton.CheckButton
    timezone *timezone.Timezone
}

type GtkColumnViewDaysAndTimes struct {
    c               *interfaces.IConfig
    id              string
    enum            int
    fieldIDs        map[int]string
    cv              *gtk.ColumnView
    prototypeFields map[string]fields
    rows            []*map[string]fields
    *dbLayer.GUI
    saveTimer    *time.Timer
    settingValue bool
}

func New(id string, enum int, config interfaces.IConfig) (dat *GtkColumnViewDaysAndTimes) {
    cv := config.GetBuilder().GetObject(id).Cast().(*gtk.ColumnView)

    applyID := id + `.Field.Apply`
    timezoneID := id + `.Field.Timezone`

    fieldIDs := map[int]string{
        0: applyID,
        1: timezoneID,
    }

    prototypeFields := map[string]fields{
        fieldIDs[0]: {apply: checkButton.New(fieldIDs[0], 0, config, false)},
        fieldIDs[1]: {timezone: timezone.New(fieldIDs[1], 0, config, false)},
    }

    dat = &GtkColumnViewDaysAndTimes{
        &config,
        id,
        enum,
        fieldIDs,
        cv,
        prototypeFields,
        []*map[string]fields{0: &prototypeFields},
        config.GetDBLayer(),
        nil,
        false,
    }

    dat.setup()
    return
}

func (dat *GtkColumnViewDaysAndTimes) setup() {
    applySignals := gtk.NewSignalListItemFactory()
    applySignals.ConnectSetup(dat.setupApply)
    applySignals.ConnectBind(dat.bindApply)

    colApply := gtk.NewColumnViewColumn(`Apply`, &applySignals.ListItemFactory)
    colApply.SetExpand(true)
    colApply.SetResizable(true)

    tzSignals := gtk.NewSignalListItemFactory()
    tzSignals.ConnectSetup(dat.setupTZ)
    tzSignals.ConnectBind(dat.bindTZ)

    colTZ := gtk.NewColumnViewColumn(`Timezone`, &tzSignals.ListItemFactory)
    colTZ.SetExpand(true)
    colTZ.SetResizable(true)

    dat.cv.AppendColumn(colApply)
    dat.cv.AppendColumn(colTZ)
    dat.cv.SetHExpand(true)

    dat.cv.SetVExpand(true)
    dat.cv.SetHExpand(true)

    lm := dat.cv.Columns()
    sm := gtk.NewSingleSelection(lm)
    dat.cv.SetModel(sm)

}

func (dat *GtkColumnViewDaysAndTimes) setupApply(listItem *gtk.ListItem) {
    child := gtk.NewCheckButton()
    child.SetVExpand(true)
    child.SetHExpand(true)
    child.SetHAlign(0)
    listItem.SetChild(child)
}

func (dat *GtkColumnViewDaysAndTimes) setupTZ(listItem *gtk.ListItem) {
    child := gtk.NewEntry()
    child.SetVExpand(true)
    child.SetHExpand(true)
    child.SetHAlign(0)
    listItem.SetChild(child)
}

var count = 1

func (dat *GtkColumnViewDaysAndTimes) bindApply(listItem *gtk.ListItem) {
    child := listItem.Child().(*gtk.CheckButton)
    child.SetLabel(`Count ` + strconv.Itoa(count))
}

func (dat *GtkColumnViewDaysAndTimes) bindTZ(listItem *gtk.ListItem) {
    child := listItem.Child().(*gtk.Entry)
    child.SetText(`Also ` + strconv.Itoa(count))
    count++
}
```

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- Created with Cambalache 0.16.0 -->
<interface>
  <!-- interface-name TradingAnalyzer.ui -->
  <!-- interface-authors Reg Proctor -->
  <requires lib="gio" version="2.0"/>
  <requires lib="gtk" version="4.6"/>
  <object class="GtkApplicationWindow" id="AppWin">
    <property name="default-height">960</property>
    <property name="default-width">1200</property>
    <property name="title">Trading Analyzer Settings</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="main_box">
        <property name="orientation">GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkPopoverMenuBar">
            <property name="halign">start</property>
            <property name="margin-bottom">10</property>
            <property name="menu-model">menu</property>
            <property name="name">General Menu</property>
            <property name="valign">start</property>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkPaned">
            <child>
              <object class="GtkFrame">
                <property name="label">Settings</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkStackSidebar">
                    <property name="halign">start</property>
                    <property name="height-request">900</property>
                    <property name="stack">Pages</property>
                    <property name="valign">start</property>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkFrame">
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkStack" id="Pages">
                    <property name="name">Timezone</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkStackPage" id="GeneralSetup">
                        <property name="child">
                          <object class="GtkFlowBox">
                            <property name="margin-bottom">20</property>
                            <property name="margin-end">50</property>
                            <property name="margin-start">50</property>
                            <property name="margin-top">20</property>
                            <property name="name">Timezone</property>
                            <child>
                              <object class="GtkEntry" id="GeneralSetup.Timezone">
                                <property name="activates-default">True</property>
                                <property name="focusable">True</property>
                                <property name="halign">start</property>
                                <property name="height-request">10</property>
                                <property name="input-purpose">alpha</property>
                                <property name="placeholder-text">Timezone</property>
                                <property name="text">America/Phoenix</property>
                                <property name="tooltip-text">Enter your timezone</property>
                                <property name="valign">center</property>
                                <property name="width-request">50</property>
                              </object>
                            </child>
                          </object>
                        </property>
                        <property name="name">General Setup</property>
                        <property name="title">General Setup</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkStackPage" id="Show">
                        <property name="child">
                          <object class="GtkLabel">
                            <property name="label">Empty Page</property>
                          </object>
                        </property>
                        <property name="title">Show</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkStackPage" id="BackTesting">
                        <property name="child">
                          <object class="GtkLabel">
                            <property name="label">Empty Page</property>
                          </object>
                        </property>
                        <property name="title">Back Testing</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkStackPage" id="BackTesting.Dates">
                        <property name="child">
                          <object class="GtkFlowBox">
                            <property name="hexpand">True</property>
                            <property name="max-children-per-line">1</property>
                            <property name="min-children-per-line">1</property>
                            <property name="valign">start</property>
                            <property name="vexpand">True</property>
                            <child>
                              <object class="GtkScrolledWindow">
                                <property name="hexpand">True</property>
                                <property name="kinetic-scrolling">False</property>
                                <property name="max-content-height">300</property>
                                <property name="min-content-height">300</property>
                                <property name="min-content-width">400</property>
                                <property name="vexpand">True</property>
                                <property name="vscrollbar-policy">always</property>
                                <child>
                                  <object class="GtkColumnView" id="BackTesting.Dates.DaysAndTimes">
                                    <property name="halign">start</property>
                                    <property name="height-request">300</property>
                                    <property name="hexpand">True</property>
                                    <property name="single-click-activate">True</property>
                                    <property name="vadjustment">
                                      <object class="GtkAdjustment">
                                        <property name="lower">200.0</property>
                                        <property name="step-increment">10.0</property>
                                        <property name="upper">400.0</property>
                                        <property name="value">300.0</property>
                                      </object>
                                    </property>
                                    <property name="vexpand">True</property>
                                    <property name="width-request">300</property>
                                  </object>
                                </child>
                              </object>
                            </child>
                          </object>
                        </property>
                        <property name="name">BackTesting.Dates</property>
                        <property name="title">    Dates</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
  <menu id="menu">
    <submenu>
    </submenu>
  </menu>
</interface>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured this out finally. The mistake is that when I think of a list I'm automatically thinking of rows however in this model they also consider the columns a list and being founded on a list model. I was feeding the column model in the function for the rows and the rows need their own list.

This get verified when you realize there are two columns and the whole thing is stuck on two rows.